# Firefox Addon SDK: Ways to display options to user?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm quite new to addon development with firefox. I picked the addon sdk for porting my chrome extension to firefox.

What would you suggest  to display a options page / options panel / options window to a user?

Loading a options.html file from my addon directory works quite fine (addTab(data.url("options.html"));), but i can't attach page-mods to it, as far as a i know. Therefore i can't communicate with the main.js to save my options, right?

Also how should the user access it?
In chrome this is quite easy. Rightclick your icon -> options and it opens up for you.
Are there ways to create a simliar behaviour for firefox?

Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting with the Add-on SDK 1.4 you have the [`simple-prefs` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs). It will automatically generate inline options for your add-on - these are displayed directly on your extension's page in the Add-ons Manager. That should be the preferred way to display options. The downside: opening the options programmatically is non-trivial, even for classic add-ons. And the SDK doesn't seem to support complicated controls ([documentation of what's possible with inline options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Inline_Options)), only the most basic ones.

If you want to roll your own, you probably want to integrate an "Options" button into a [drop-down panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Attaching_panels_to_buttons). You should also be able to attach a content script to it via [`page-mod` package](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), something like this should work:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: data.url("options.html"),
  ...
});

var tabs = require("tabs");
tabs.open(data.url("options.html"));
```

Downside here: using the standardized way to display add-on options (via Add-ons Manager) won't be possible, the SDK doesn't support anything but inline options.

Comment: All right, used the simple-prefs module. Works fine, thanks for that!

Comment: finally i completed a nice implementation of what you said. I'll surely post the working sample of what i did.. thanks for the hints..

Comment: To hide address and search bars you can use `addon-page` module. Downside is it demands file to be called "index.html", so until they make it right there is a user made module [addon-tab](https://github.com/lduros/addon-tab).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks `Wladimir Palant` for pointing out the direction, yet it still took me quite a while to figure out the final code. I put my result here for reference of others in the future. (I simplified the code a little bit here for elaboration purpose, but the main structure should be correct.)

content.js: (click a link to open the options page)

```
  $("#options").click(function(){
    self.port.emit("open_options", {});
  });
```

background.js:

```
//regsiter the event
backgroundInit = function(worker) {
  worker.port.on("open_options", function(request){
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    tabs.open({
      //open a new tab to display options page
      url: self.data.url("options.html"),
    });
  }

  worker.port.on("pull_preferences", function(request){
    var preferences = null;
    //get preferences (from simple storage or API)
    woker.emit("update_content_preferences", {preferences:preferences});
  });


  worker.port.on("push_preferences", function(request){
    var preferences = request.preferences;
    //write the preferences (to simple storage or API)
  });
}

//register the page, note that you could register multiple ones
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: self.data.url('options.html'),
  contentScriptFile: [ self.data.url("lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"),
                        self.data.url("options.js")],
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',  
  onAttach: backgroundInit

});
```

options.js: (this page is also on the content script context)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  self.port.on("update_content_preferences", function(request){
    var preferences = request.preferences;
    //update options page values using the preferences
  });

  $("#save").click(function(){
    var preferences = null;
    //get preferences from options page
    self.port.emit("push_preferences", {preferences:preferences});
  });

  self.port.emit("pull_preferences", {}); //trigger the pull upon page start
});
```

Reference: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs

Answer (score -1):

In this case you need to use Port.on()/Port.emit() to send a controll option from options.html, like click on setting button. And "tabs" module

```
 options.html

        var panelIsOpen = 0;

        $('#settings').click(function() {
                self.port.emit("statusoptions", {optionsIsOpen:1});
            });

 popup.html

        Panel.port.on("statusoptions", function (panda) {
                if(panda.optionsIsOpen === 1){
                    Panel.hide();
                    tabs.open({
                        url: "options.html",
                        onReady: function onReady(tab) {
                           Panel.hide();
                        },
                        contentScriptFile: [
                            data.url("js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"),
                            data.url("js/options.js")],
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried, and the it did not work. In particular, it's impossible to access `self.port` from the `options.html`.