# Firefox addon, create own options page (not simple-prefs/preferences)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create an option page for my first addon. I don't want to use simple-prefs, it doesn't have the types that I need. So how do I create my own options page?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195774/firefox-addon-sdk-ways-to-display-options-to-user) post. But [widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget) has been removed in firefox 38, so what are other ways to create own options page?

BTW, the firefox's add-on API seems to be very VERY disorganized. Old-dated information and not consistence. Is there a better place/forum/group to look up latest info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to do this.

This is a repo of a simple html options demo page: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/html-options

The important parts are:

- optionsType should be 3 - https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/blob/html-options/install.rdf#L12
- set path: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/blob/html-options/install.rdf#L13
- define path with chroem.manifest on line 1: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/blob/html-options/chrome.manifest#L1
- create a options page in html - https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/blob/html-options/my_options.xhtml

Now this repository makes an `xhtml` page because this repository shows at the same time a fully localized addon. With xhtml you can use replacements, i highly advise you do the same. When you do use xhtml though make sure to close all typically non-closed tags, like br, img, input, etc tags like: `<br>` should now be `<br/>` otherwise youll get xml errors

This repository also shows how to localize your install.rdf, I recommend you fork this repository for the start of your addon.

Comment: is there a way to do it in the package.json format? I think the install.rdf and chrome manifest are the legacy way of doing it? I am not sure. Documentation on Firefox add-on site is not helpful at all.

Comment: chrome.manifest method is bootstrap method, similar to legaxy (xul overlay) method but not exactly. when you create an xpi out of your package.json format addon (addon-sdk version) it creates a chrome.manifest and install.rdf, so addon-sdk is a subset of bootstrap addons. I dont know how to do this in addon-sdk/package.json method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it some other time. I love using firefox but the barrier to create an extension is just too high. I spent ~20 hours on learning the platform and still haven't gotten anywhere. And I finished an extension in ~5 hours on Google Chrome. I am new to both platforms. Sigh...

Comment: @Z-1 you can try converting the google chrome extension with chrome tailor: https://github.com/erikvold/chrome-tailor its quite simple making a firefox addon so dont give up if you need help jump onto irc https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23extdev im always there as noida