# creating a page with a blank address bar via firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to open a tab with a firefox addon and clear the address bar like about:blank, about:newtab etc. does ?

Comment: does opening a page with the URL about:blank or about:newtab do what you want?

Comment: @JaromandaX well this is a example how I want the effect to be, but I want my addon to open a page (its a new tab page that I created) but with a blank address bar. So it should not display `resurces://myaddon/data/the.html`

Comment: and if you could have an url like `about:foobar`? will this do the job? If yes, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34169673/3219121)

Comment: @matagus well this is like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut ... this might be a way (I am not sure that this will clear the address bar) but I have one other I will try out and if it works I will post back.